# How do I iterate through a sequence of shared_ptr objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, shared-ptr

This is more a styling than performance question. I have just converted (most of) my pointers to shared_ptr objects, and have reluctantly come to accept weak_ptrs as alternatives to raw pointers. My question is, what is the preferred method of iterating through a sequence (let's say a vector) of shared pointer objects? Here is what I've been doing:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> my_sequence;
// Do something to fill my_sequence;

for (std::shared_ptr<A> const& ptr : my_sequence)
{
  ptr->AMethod();
}
```

This goes against the *don't use shared_ptr references* rule though, so what's a good alternative, and why?

Questions I would be asking are; Is the technique robust, ie. For AMethod() super tiny, and my_sequence super large, will this method start to impede performance unecessarily due to shared_ptr copies? Is it readable? Is it simple?

Comment: What would `auto` do?  (WWAD)

Comment: Create a copy of shared_ptr<A>?

Comment: I'm curious about this myself, as I'm not very C++11 saavy yet and don't have a compiler available to fiddle with

Comment: Where does that rule come from??  I tend to think at least one expert, Sutter, would disagree.

Comment: If you use a reference in your range-based for then you won't make unnecessary copies. What you are doing is fine, `auto& ptr` would also be fine.

Comment: `shared_ptr` isn't a panacea. It should be used when ownership is actually shared. Non-sharing ownership is expressed by `unique_ptr` and non-ownership is expressed by a (raw) reference. `weak_ptr` is for a `shared_ptr` that must be observed but not owned… but isn't a good defensive practice against stale pointers in general. This is going to the lowest common denominator, not good programming practice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a disclaimer:

`shared_ptr` isn't a panacea. It should be used when ownership is actually shared. Non-sharing ownership is expressed by `unique_ptr` and non-ownership is expressed by a (raw) reference. `weak_ptr` is for a `shared_ptr` that must be observed but not owned… but isn't a good defensive practice against stale pointers in general. Defaulting to `shared_ptr` goes directly to the lowest common denominator; it's poor programming practice.

---

The choice here is between `shared_ptr< T >`, `shared_ptr< T const >`, `shared_ptr< T > const &`, and `T const &`, and `T &`. Let's assume you're not changing anything, but the sequence *could* change its objects, so `const` is desirable. That narrows it to `shared_ptr< T const >`, `shared_ptr< T > const &`, and `T const &`.

Let's reformulate the question as,

> Is `shared_ptr< T > const &` ever the right choice?

In this light, evaluate the alternatives.

- `shared_ptr< T const >` (pass shared pointer by value)

  - +: straightforward value semantics; can pass `shared_ptr< T >`
  - +: can be copied or `move`d to expand the ownership pool
  - +: propagates `const` correctness to the called function
  - +: access to object is fast: a direct pointer argument is included
  - –: passing is expensive: copies two machine words and atomic-touches a ref count
  - –: called function concerns itself with ownership semantics
- `shared_ptr< T > const &` (pass shared pointer by reference)

  - +: passing is as cheap as a direct object reference
  - +: can be copied to expand the ownership pool
  - –: loses `const` correctness to the called function

    - If you try `shared_ptr< T const > const &` instead, you will pass a temporary copy and end up with the disadvantages of this alternative and pass-by-value.
  - –: access to object goes through an extra indirection
  - –: called function concerns itself with ownership semantics
- `T const &` (direct reference)

  - +: preserves `const` correctness
  - +: caller unconcerned with ownership semantics
  - +: pass fast, just one machine word
  - +: access fast, direct pointer argument to function (if even that)
  - –: cannot confer ownership

Weighing it on balance, if ownership isn't being extended (such as by returning an object that retains the argument), you really should pass a simple reference. In such a case, the function should seldom care how its argument is owned. Having it require a `shared_ptr` violates separation of concerns in the worst way. You can't have a local object or a member subobject and still use the function. And worst of all, everything is more complicated.

If ownership is potentially extended to someone else, which would be the justification for using `shared_ptr` in the first place, then you should always pass by `shared_ptr< [const] T >` value. Yes, it does copy the `shared_ptr` upon call. But the expensive part of copying a `shared_ptr` is updating the refcount, not pushing the pointers on the stack. And if you're conferring ownership, you want to update the refcount anyway. Take the passed value and `move` it, which does *not* touch the refcount. Having done that, you're left with no advantages and a lot of disadvantages to pass-by-reference.

Comment: This is a good answer. Def like the pro/con analysis.  However, I have a couple of difficulties with it, such as what are you trying to say here?

`But the expensive part of copying a shared_ptr is updating the refcount, not pushing the pointers on the stack.`

And here you say to `move` it?

`Take the passed value and move it, which does not touch the refcount.`

Do you mean the `shared_ptr`?  How would you get it back to the caller?  Or are you suggesting that it if you are not going to passing it back?

Comment: @Adrian I'm saying if you pass a `shared_ptr`, pass it by value. This will update the refcount (retain it) immediately, and on most ABIs also pass a direct pointer to the object and a "control" pointer. If you're concerned with performance, simply passing things is fast but updating the refcount is slower. The only good reason for passing a `shared_ptr` (by value) is if you want to retain it for longer than the function call, so the function should take its direct argument and `move` that, and its extra retention, to something persistent. It's copied from the caller, not moved, so all is well.

Comment: Agreed. The only time I could say that this is not necessarily optimum is if ownership is passed conditionally, in which case it may not be necessary to update the ref counter.

Answer (score 9):

The reason for not using shared_ptr references is because you defeat the mechanism that it is trying to protect yourself from.  I.e. having a potentially dangling pointer.  If you are iterating through a container, this shouldn't be a problem since objects will not disappear on you unexpectedly.  You just shouldn't store a shared_ptr reference which you may use later.

I.e. This is bad:

```
struct Y
{
    int y;
    Y() : y(1) {}
};

struct X
{
     shared_ptr<Y>& ref_shared_ptr_y;
     X(shared_ptr<Y>& y) : ref_shared_ptr_y(y) {}
};

void main()
{
    shared_ptr<Y> shared_ptr_y(new Y());
    X x(shared_ptr_y);
    y.reset();
    x.ref_shared_ptr_y->y;  // UB since x.ref_shared_ptr_y was deleted
}
```

`shared_ptr` should only be used if you really need object ownership to be shared between 2 or more locations.  It causes unnecessary overhead otherwise and shows you haven't really thought the owner relationships through.  If you have ownership limited to one location, use a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: This extends to raw pointers and references vs `shared_pointer` in general. If there's no issue of ownership, `shared_pointer` is the wrong tool. (God forbid you link two `shared_pointers` independently to the same object.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter So are you saying that my method is fine as long as share pointers are actually warranted?

Comment: @ausairman Well, no. Ya know what… I'll write an answer. Stand by.